# Does Ripple use NTP?

Tags: ripple, network, time

Does Ripple use NTP or expect the nodes to do so?

If not, why not?  It seems that Ripple is a little more closed than your standard cryptocurrency, so this doesn't seem like an excessive demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ripple server has SNTP support to tolerate system clocks that are inaccurate.

The consensus process also builds a consensus network time. Each validator pulls the consensus network time a bit closer to their local time. This consensus network time becomes the close times included in ledgers that support features like expiring cross-currency offers.

Comment: We're client-server between the server and the client. We're p2p among servers. Anyone who wants to can run a server. We don't want to gratuitously cause problems just because someone's clock is off.